# How to serialize a byte array to send as the body of an HTTP POST?

Tags: java, arrays, http, post, gzip

How can a Java byte array be properly serialized to send in the body of a POST request?

Is it correct to simply invoke the `toString()` method?

Specifically, I am compressing a string with gzip, storing in a `byte[]` array, serializing, and sending to an http POST endpoint. Ty.

EDIT: For posterity, I was using the `java.net.http.HttpRequest` library, which provides different methods for various body types; for example:

```
HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(msg_byte_arr)
HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(msg_str)
```

Comment: Calling `System.out.println((new byte[]{1,3,4}).toString());` yields  `[B@36baf30c`.  You can use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream classes.

Comment: I meant, use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream classes if you want to send serialized objects. As rzwitserloot suggested write the byte[] to getOutputStream directly no need to serialize it.

Answer (score 2):

a byte[] array is ready to send straight as a POST request - you should have a `.getOutputStream()` method, which gets you an output stream (make sure to guard it using try-with-resources). Call its `.write()` method. Do not use the `ObjectOutputStream` advised in a comment.

Comment: Or, if using most libraries, a `byte[]` can be passed in the various places you'd send a body.